# Check each div for id based upon values within an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a set of tabs based upon an existing set of categories with the below JS. **I need to extend this to target specific id's within the DIV id based upon values from a JS array.**

```
        $("#categories div[id^=category]:not(:first)", this).hide();

        var cats = $('#categories div[id^=category]');

        cats.each(function () {
           var anch = $(this).find('h3 a').eq(1).clone();
            anch[0].rel = this.id;
            $('<li/>').append(anch).appendTo('#tabs');
        });
```

The html:

```
<div id="category_1">
    <h3 class="maintitle">
        <a class="toggle">..</a>
        <a href="#">Cat 1 Title</a>
    </h3>
    <div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>

<div id="category_2">
    <h3 class="maintitle">
        <a class="toggle">..</a>
        <a href="#">Cat 2 Title</a>
    </h3>
    <div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I've got a JS array ready by adding:

```
var catsList = '{$cats}'; // comma separated list of numbers generated in PHP - returns 1,4,8 currently.
var catsArray = catsList.split(',');
```

How would I convert the below, to check for each item within catsArray ?

```
var cats = $('#categories div[id^=category]');
```

Something like

```
var cats = $('#categories div[id^=category_'+catsArray+']');
```

but obviously checking each item within the array and not the entire array as that's doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use that as IDs have to be unique on context page:

```
var cats = $('#category_'+catsArray.join(',#category_'));
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/debt5/)

Answer (score 2):

you probably want the [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function

```
$.each(catsArray,function(index, item) {
       var cats = $('#categories div[id^=category_'+item+']');
 });
```

Depending on how you using this a [for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript) will do it also:

```
for (var i = 0; i < catsArray.length; i++) {
   var catIndex = catsArray[i];
   var cats = $('#categories div[id^=category_'+catIndex +']');
}
```